# Replace a complex if else statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods

I am looking for a clean and effective way of accomplishing this (See picture). I want to stack different buttons side by side depending on if they are visible or not. I started out by using if else statements but this way of doing it got fast very complicated and ineffective.

[image]

- Case 1: Only one button is visible. Align is center.
- Case 2: Displaying another button. Two buttons are visible.
- Case 3: Displaying an OFF button. Three buttons are visible.
- Case 4: Hiding ON and Close. OFF is center.
- Case 5: A fourth new button is added to the stack/page.

  ```
  //Buttons
  private int startX { get; set; }
  private int width { get; set; }
  private int gap { get; set; }   

  private Boolean showOnBtn { get; set; }
  private Boolean showOffBtn { get; set; }
  private Boolean showCloseBtn { get; set; }

  public Buttons(int startX, int width, int gap)
  {
      this.startX = startX;
      this.width = width;
      this.gap = gap;
  }
  ```

Example of my if else attempt:

```
        //Page
        width = 600px;

        Button onBtn = new Button();

        Private void Update(){

        if (showOnBtn){

        onBtn.startX = 242;
        onBtn.width = 116;
        onBtn.gap = 0;

        if (showOffBtn || showCloseBtn) {

        onBtn.startX = 126;
        onBtn.width = 116;
        onBtn.gap = 113;
        etc etc…

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't even know if this is the web or what.  But for such an ad-hoc UX, very simply just have **five totally different panels** - your designers can design each panel perfectly as desired - and just cycle through them.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: @Joe Blow Thank you. That is a good idea

Comment: @TaW Ok. I am sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the abstract, you must have five totally different panels.

A **basic pattern** in software engineering is:

- if you have to turn "only one one",
- you ***have a routine that simply turns ALL of them off***,
- and then ***just turn the one on***.

In other words, "turn them all off, each time" and just turn on the one newly-desired one.  Don't try to "turn some on and off" etc.

Abstract code:

```
function TurnAllOff()
 {
 for i = 1 ... 5 Buttons[i].Hide();
 }

function ShowThisOne(int i)
 {
 TurnAllOff()
 Buttons[i].Show()
 }
```

I have utterly no clue if you are working in Unity, the www, or whatever. But you will have to have precisely the above code (just in your local syntax).

That's all there is to it. You ***can not*** generalize the layout, in your case.

Have ***five different*** perfect layouts for the five different button systems.

Use the pattern above to choose one at any time.

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a switch case:

```
switch (caseDecider)
        {
            //ON/OFF
            case 1:
                //set UI elements to apropriate states here
                break;
            //ON/CLOSE//OFF
            case 2:
                //set UI elements to apropriate states here
                break;
            //OFF
            case 3:
                //set UI elements to apropriate states here
                break;
            //ON/CLOSE/OFF/NEW
            case 4:
                //set UI elements to apropriate states here
                break;
            //ON
            default:
                //set UI elements to apropriate states here
                break;
        }
```

you'll just need to figure out where you are setting the "caseDecider" variable, and where you are placing the switch.  Switches are often a better option than if/else because of readability, flexibility, and requiring less typing.

EDIT:  if you want to simplify setting each of your 5 states, write a function that sets each state. Something like:

```
private void setState1()
        {
                onBtn.startX = 242;
                onBtn.width = 116;
                onBtn.gap = 0;
        }
```

for each state.  Then you just call that function whenever you want to set that state.

Comment: You don't need to do this.  Just go `ShowThisOne(i)`.  switch is rarely a good construct, it just means you have not generalized enough.